# Angular distance/apparent separation between AE Aurigae and Orion's belt

Tags: distances, positional-astronomy, astrometry

The title perhaps gives the question away, but would anyone know/be able to roughly approximate the angular distance/apparent separation between AE Aurigae and Orion's belt.

I have the value of $42^\circ$, from visual estimation but would like a way to calculate this.

Comment: Suggest you show your working by telling what you have done to find this and the value you got.

Comment: Purely by visual inspection and a little help from nova.astrometry.net

Comment: @JamesKilfiger Many thanks for the link to the angular distance calculator. Very useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the cords of AE aurigae:

**RA 05h 16m 18.1s DEC +34° 18' 49"**

And Alnitak in Orion's belt:

**RA 05h 40m 45.52666s DEC  −01° 56′ 34.2649″**

I get an angular separation of 34.83°

By this formula:

$\cos(A) = \sin(\mathrm{DEC}_1)\cdot \sin(\mathrm{DEC}_2) + \cos(\mathrm{DEC}_1)\cdot \cos(\mathrm{DEC}_2)\cdot \cos(\mathrm{RA}_1 - \mathrm{RA}_2)$

Comment: Useful link: http://www.gyes.eu/calculator/calculator_page1.htm

Comment: I was a little off at 42 degrees. That was by visual inspection.

Comment: I was going from M42 as well.

Comment: @MichaelJRoberts It helps to know the destination :)